# how to make a div draggable in vue js?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a div inside a vue component, I want to make the component draggable. I checked with many vue draggable plugins, but they have a seperate component for drag and not as a directive to just add like in angular draggable. Please help me with this?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't wrap your div in a draggable component? I've been using https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable a lot lately and it is literally just plug&play with no problems whatsoever...

Comment: I tried wrapping the div in a drag component, but my use case is such that on selection of text on the page, a modal has to pop up and it has to be draggable. the modal is draggable if I put the div in the component, but the selection gets cleared on drag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add vuedraggable to your node modules.

yarn add vuedraggable

and then:

```
  import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
  ...
  export default {
        components: {
            draggable,
        }
```

and then you need something like this:

```
<draggable>
    <div v-for=...>
    </div>
</draggable>
```

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Comment: The problem with this is, vuedraggable expects some list/array to be passed to it and in the scenarios where we have some modal and want to drag it by its header, its not sufficient.