# sliding frames in javascript and vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a page similar to trello in javascript using vue.js
What can I use to make such sliding frames - arrays with tasks inside?
it is about an element that can be grabbed with a mouse and moved to another place

Comment: A quick google of "dragging div vue" shows https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-directive-for-handling-element-drag-and-drop/ and https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable. Maybe duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988914/how-to-make-a-div-draggable-in-vue-js

Answer (score 0):

Trello board is an implementation of a `Kanban board`. So while searching in Google, that should be your keyword.

https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-kanban e.g. is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Found this example for your concern : https://vuejsexamples.com/a-realtime-kanban-board-in-vue-js-and-hamoni-sync/. It seems to be quite what you need to begin with...